# Calibration of probabilities in online learning (real-time learning) with Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: regression, skewness

How exactly Real-Time Learning techniques deal with the problem of skewed distribution in dependent and independent variables? I am getting acquainted with Vowpal Wabbit and face this problem. My data have mixed types of variables (numeric and nominal). I use it for regression and classification. I understand that probabilities I am getting still need to be calibrated, correct?

I know that imbalance in present in the domain, but as real-time learning accumulates training examples, how does that work? Imbalance (skewed distribution) in independent variable is also a problem in regression, so how is that resolved? I suppose all those sophisticated techniques are developed to handle these problems, but I need some details to begin with.